# Как в масив строк добавить ещё одну

Tags: c++, массивы, curl, visual-studio-2015, переменные

Всё не так просто как кажется =)
Есть переменная It, так вот её нужно вставить вместо The body of the message starts here.\r\n
Вот код =)

```
#include "Header.h"
#define FROM_ADDR    "lashka.luhovna@yandex.ua"
#define TO_ADDR      "plavenkov@yandex.ua"
#define CC_ADDR      "Lasha Luhovna<lashka.luhovna@yandex.ua> (ABC Company), lashka.witch@herssite.com"
#define FROM_MAIL "Sender Person " FROM_ADDR
#define TO_MAIL   "A Receiver " TO_ADDR
#define CC_MAIL   "Message " CC_ADDR

///////////////////////////////////////////
time_t It = time(NULL);
static const char *payload_text[] = {
    "Date: Mon, 10 Nov 2018 21:54:29 +1100\r\n",
    "To: " TO_MAIL "\r\n",
    "From: " FROM_MAIL "\r\n",
    "Cc: " CC_MAIL "\r\n",
    "Message-ID: <dcd7cb36-11db-487a-9f3a-e652a9458efd@"
    "rfcpedant.example.org>\r\n",
    "Subject: SMTP example message\r\n",
    "\r\n", /* empty line to divide headers from body, see RFC5322 */
    "The body of the message starts here.\r\n",
    "\r\n",
    "It could be a lot of lines, could be MIME encoded, whatever.\r\n",
    "Check RFC5322.\r\n",
    NULL
};
//Дальше идёт ненужная вам шняга =)
```

Comment: прошу прощения, не строку, а time_t

Comment: Если это невозможно, то скажите что надо делать, если It = "Hello";

Comment: если It = "Hello", то `asprintf(&payload_text[8], "%s\r\n", It);`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <ctime>

// ==================
// в какой-то функции
tm *timeinfo = localtime(&It);
char* stime = asctime(timeinfo);
```

Ну и вставляете значение `stime` по вашему индексу в массиве.

```
payload_text[8] = stime;
```